# Price of variable products (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tell me please. Where does the basket get the value of the variational product, with the subsequent multiplication by the number and the issuance of the **TOTAL** and the **SUBTOTAL**? The problem is that you need to send the cost of the products from an custom field to the basket.

For a simple product, everything turned out. The following function was added to the file **abstract-wc-product.php**:

```
public function get_rrp_price( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_meta( $key = 'rrp_price', $context = 'view' );
}
```

Where **rrp_price** - is the name of an arbitrary field with a new price. Then in the template **class-wc-cart.php** , namely in the following functions:

```
public function calculate_totals(
public function get_product_subtotal(
```

I am replaced **$product->get_price()** with **$product->get_rrp_price()** and for a **simple product it all worked!**

But when you add a variable product, the basket issues **ZERO**. I can not understand in what place it can be fixed, I guess that in **class-wc-product-variable.php**, but if so, where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this problem before but i found the solution please check below code i think from that you can get perfect idea.

```
function opal_varient_price( $price, $variation ) {

if (  $variation->product_type == 'variation'  ) {

    $user = $user ? new WP_User( $user ) : wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    if($role == 'detailer'){$pricex = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, 'dist',true);}
    else if($role == 'reseller'){$pricex = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, 'res',true);}  
    else{ $pricex = $price;}
    }
return $pricex;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'opal_varient_price' , 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'opal_varient_price' , 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'opal_varient_price', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: You just need to add hook in "woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price"

Comment: Thank you for answer! But where to place this hook?

Comment: Just add it in function.php of your theme and make sure you have changed code with yours

Comment: $pricex should be your custom field price.

Comment: how can I change a usual custom field to custom price field?
or it does not matter?
My custom field name - 'rrp_price'.

Comment: you just need to asssign $pricex = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, 'rrp_price',true);

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to this (changed **'dist'** and **'rest'** for **'rrp_price'**):

```
function opal_varient_price( $price, $variation ) {

if (  $variation->product_type == 'variation'  ) {

    $user = $user ? new WP_User( $user ) : wp_get_current_user();
    $role = $user->roles[0];
    if($role == 'detailer'){$pricex = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, 'rrp_price',true);}
    else if($role == 'reseller'){$pricex = get_post_meta( $variation->variation_id, 'rrp_price',true);}  
    else{ $pricex = $price;}
    }
return $pricex;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'opal_varient_price' , 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'opal_varient_price' , 99, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'opal_varient_price', 99, 2 );
```

But variable products still **ZERO** in a cart.

Comment: Use `$variation->get_id()` Instead `$variation->variation_id`